# Woocommerce Cart - parsing shortcode within cart output

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Bit of an unusual customisation in WooCommerce that I require...

I've modified the standard WooCommerce cart.php so that the customer can't edit the quantity or remove items from cart. Basically, the customer first visits a seating plan page, selects their seat, and this then adds the relevant ticket (which is just a WC product) to their cart, and displays the cart page.

I want a column in the cart output, which has a button next to every row (every ticket) directing the customer back to the relevant seating plan for that ticket.

I've stored the seating plan shortcode in the WooCommerce product details, and I'm able to recall this in cart.php, and it displays in the right place as text using this line of code:

```
<td class="product-seating" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Seating Plan', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
<?php echo the_field('wccaf_seating_plan_link', $product_id) ; ?>
</td>
```

This returns the following text nicely under a Seating Plan column in the cart for every ticket:

[tc_seat_chart id="3818" show_legend="true" button_title="Select your seat(s)" subtotal_title="Subtotal" cart_title="Continue to Checkout"]

However, what I actually want it to do is parse this shortcode, which should create a nice button with a link to the correct seating plan.

How would I make it parse the shortcode and not just display it as text? I tried playing around with do_shortcode but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td class="product-seating" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Seating Plan', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
<?php $seating_plan = get_field('wccaf_seating_plan_link', $product_id) ;
echo do_shortcode($seating_plan);
?>
</td>
```